# Fixed scroll is jerky on chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, parallax

i'm writing a bit of code to get a fixed scroll effect on some divs with background image (So the div is moving in page, but background move at the same time, like a simple parallax effect)

I started with jQuery but, as i say in the title, the background image is jerky (That's to say, i assume the background is scrolled normally during few ms before to be reset on the fixed position by the script). So i also try without jQuery to test, but it's not the problem. It's not the first time i have this problem on chrome... I tried to set a -webkit-transform: translateZ(0); on my el, just in case, but without effect.

Here is my (tiny) code :

```
$(document).scroll(function() {

    var el = document.getElementById('parentEl'), el2 = el.firstChild, top = 0;

    el2.style.top = (window.pageYOffset-el.offsetTop)+'px';

})
```

Here the parent is relative and the famous div absolute, but i also try with relative div and backgroundPositionY, same result.

Thanks !

Comment: Why are you mixing document.getElementById with jQuery?  You should stick to either using the jQuery framework and its selectors or not. document.getElementById('parentE1') can be replaced with $('#parentE1')[0]

Comment: Read my message, i started with jQuery and try without to ckeck it wasn't it. But it's not the subject and the code is correct, you absolutly can shake both together.